Add methods to CreateApp Function Vue3 typescript
I am learning vue3 and am using typescript for it. Is there a way to pass in the state and behavior from the root of the application.
// main.ts
const app = createApp(App, {
    cart: 0,
    imagePath: "/src/assets/images/socks_blue.png",
    product: "Socks",
    description: "Some description",
    details: ["50% cotton", "30% wool", "20% polyester"],
    variants: [
        { id: 2235, color: 'green' },
        { id: 2234, color: 'blue' },
    ],
    sizes: ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL'],
    stockStatus: true,
    onSale: false,
    // addToCart: () => { cart += 1 } doesn't work.
});

app.mount("#app");

and then access the state and behavior in App.
// App.vue
<div class="product-display">
    <div class="product-container">
      <div class="product-image">
        <ImageDisplay :imagePath=imagePath />
      </div>
      <div class="product-info">
        <ProductDisplay 
        :product=product 
        :description=description
        :details=details
        :variants=variants
        :sizes=sizes
        :stockStatus=stockStatus
        :onSale=onSale />
        <button class="button">Add to Cart</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

The default state is passed to App and can be accessed without any issue but not sure how to pass in the methods from main.ts to App.vue and use it there when the button is clicked.
Still learning so not sure if this the right way to pass default state around and update it.

Why do you want to do it on the instance itself? Make it in a component rather. Check this example: https://vuejs.org/examples/#simple-component You can set the syntax to HTML in the upper left part.

I have tried what you have recommended but was not able to get it working. I am sure I was doing something wrong.

By using the below I was able to create the App render it with default props and pass in events to update the props.
import { createApp, reactive, h } from 'vue'
import "./assets/styles.css"
import App from './App.vue'

// Define your default props here
const defaultProps = reactive({
    cart: 0,
    imagePath: "/src/assets/images/socks_blue.png",
    product: "Socks",
    description: "Some description",
    details: ["50% cotton", "30% wool", "20% polyester"],
    variants: [
        { id: 2235, color: 'green' },
        { id: 2234, color: 'blue' },
    ],
    sizes: ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL'],
    stockStatus: true,
    onSale: false,
    updateCart() {
        defaultProps.cart += 1;
    }
  });


const app = createApp({
    render() {
        return h(App, defaultProps);
    }
});

